# Cool Number Counter

Tags: java

For this lab a cool number is any number that when divided by 3,4,5 & 6 will leave a remainder of 1. I have done the static boolean IsCoolNumber and I made a private int b to use as a counter but I have absolutely no idea where I would put for example a b++. Any help would greatly be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class CoolNumbers 
{
    private int b=0;

    public static boolean isCoolNumber( int num )
    {
        int x; 
        x = 6;
        for(x = 6; x<num; x++)
        {
        if ((x%3==1)  &&  (x%4==1)  && (x%5 ==1) && (x%6 == 1))

            return true;

        }
        return false;

    }

    public static int countCoolNumbers( int stop )
    {


        //add counter


    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( CoolNumbers.countCoolNumbers(250) + " cool numbers between 6 - " + 250);
        //add more test cases
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your algorithm? How are you going about tackling the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `isCoolNumber` you don't need a loop, a single statement will do.

```
public static boolean isCoolNumber(int x) {
    return (x % 3 == 1) && (x % 4 == 1) && (x % 5 == 1) && (x % 6 == 1);
}
```

To count the "cool numbers" add a simple loop in the currently empty `countCoolNumbers( int stop )` method.

```
for (int i = start; i < stop; i++) {
    if (isCoolNumber(i)) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your method `countCoolNumbers`as below and try it...

```
public static int countCoolNumbers( int stop ){
     boolean check=isCoolNumber(stop);
        int num=0;
      if(check==true){
        num=stop;
       }
       num=0;
     return num;
```

`}

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
System.out.println( CoolNumbers.countCoolNumbers(250) + " cool numbers between 6 - " + 250);
//add more test cases
```

}

Then output will be:

0  cool numbers between 6 -  250